# How to load image in javascript without put it in the cache

Tags: javascript, image, caching, browser

I would like to load image in javascript, like that :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.myimage.fr/myimage.jpg";
```

But i would like the image don't go in the browser's cache when she is loaded. 
It's important to keep this url, i don't want to set any parameter like a timestamp to the url.

Any idea ?

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like schoolwork?

Answer (score 2):

To do this you'll need your web server to output the appropriate headers along with the response.

You can instruct the browser to not cache the resource by setting these headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Since this is a static file you are serving (an image) you'll have to configure your web server to do this for you, based on the filename or the extension.  What web server is serving your website?

Comment: this prevents caching of all the images. I believe OP wants just specific images :)

Comment: Yes, if the config is done for all files of a specific extension, but I belive that it should be possible to configure this per filename, but then again, depends on the web server being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
-----
</head>
```